# Query multi-condition terms at the same level in elastic search. It seems the conditions are not intersected

Tags: elasticsearch

I am not sure if I could use nested query. Because the origin record are not typed as a nested document.

I have a recode like this:

```
{
"name":"Jack",
"event":[
{"jobname:job1","result:good"},
{"jobname:job2","result:bad"},
{"jobname:job3","result:soso"},
]
},
{
"name":"Andy",
"event":[
{"jobname:job1","result:bad"},
{"jobname:job2","result:bad"},
{"jobname:job3","result:good"},
]
}      
}
```

I am wondering how to get "jobname":"job1" and "job2:bad" in one query?

I tried:

```
POST index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter":[ 
        {"terms":{"event.jobname":["job1"]}},
        {"terms":{"event.result":["good"]}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And supposed to get Jack's record only. But I got Jack and Andy's record. It seems these two conditions ("jobname:job1","result:good") are not intersected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TLDr;

`Elastic` flatten objects. Such that

```json
    {
      "group" : "fans",
      "user" : [ 
        {
          "first" : "John",
          "last" :  "Smith"
        },
        {
          "first" : "Alice",
          "last" :  "White"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Turn into:

```json
    {
      "group" :        "fans",
      "user.first" : [ "alice", "john" ],
      "user.last" :  [ "smith", "white" ]
    }
```

You need to [update your mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) to use [nested field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html). This is going to prevent Elasticsearch from `flatenning` your data.